# How to share a part of a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial

I have a [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) repository hosted in [Bitbucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket). As of now I have made it private. But I intend to share a few of the documents with other people. Is there a way, I can share only that particular file of a folder of my repository with other people?

If not, is there any other solution apart from mailing him/her that content?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can't. What you can do is either take the files out, or if the history is important, create a new repository with the rest of the files filtered out (see hg convert documentation, specifically `--filemap` option). Just keep in mind you won't be able to pull and push between those two.